# CRM 2011 for Outlook Emails - How Does The Regarding Link Work?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-addin

This question specifically pertains to the CRM 2011 for Outlook client. We have emails that are sent via Workflows to certain users. All of the email messages have the Regarding field set when they are created by the Workflow. Only some of them have the clickable link at the bottom of the email in the "CRM Pane".

Can anyone explain how that works? Does it only work for certain entities? Does the entity have to be email enabled (even though I've set the Regarding field)?

I really can't find any explanation as to how this works. I only know that emails that are Regarding an Account have the link and emails Regarding a Custom Entity do not. I need to get the custom entity emails to have the link also.

FYI I've got the Track Emails between users as 2 activities unchecked although I've tried it both ways.